# Firebase cloud functions - Object cannot be encoded in JSON - Kotlin data class

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-functions

Currently, I am trying to call a https firebase cloud functions inside my android app. The only problem I get is, that when I try to call the function with some data, I get the error:

"Object cannot be encoded in JSON".

My Question is: How can I solve this problem? The Object I am trying to pass is a kotlin data class. Do I have to manually convert the data to a json object first (with gson) or is there a better solution?

This is my current solution: (not working, getting internal error)

### Data class

```
data class UserDeliveryAddress(
    val company: String? = "",
    val fullName: String = "",
    val postcode: Int = 0,
    val city: String = "",
    val street: String = "",
    val houseNumber: Int = 0,
    val country: String = "",
)
```

### Usage

```
if (optionalAdress != null) {
    val data = gson.toJson(userDeliveryNetworkEntityMapper.mapToEntity(optionalAdress))

    dbFunctions.getHttpsCallable("authOnCreate")
        .call(data) // just getting "internal" error
        .await()
}
```

### Cloud Function

```
export async function doOnAuthCreate(data: any, context: functions.https.CallableContext) {
    functions.logger.info("AUTH ON CREATE - Creating new user");

    const dataObject = JSON.parse(data);
    
    functions.logger.info(`Country is: ${dataObject.country}`);

    functions.logger.info("AUTH ON CREATE - Sucessfully created user");
    return 0;
}
```

### Index.ts

```
import { doOnAuthCreate } from "./auth/onCreate.f"

export const authOnCreate = functions
    .region(region)
    .https
    .onCall(doOnAuthCreate);
```

Comment: Did you try to convert the JSON to a HashMap? I think the callable functions accept HashMaps as data.

Comment: @TarikHuber Yes I did, still Internal Error. I think there is a problem with the local emulator. I created a new hashmap but still, not working. Have to find another solution

Comment: Can you try to JSONfy your data before calling the callable function?

Comment: @FaridShumbar Didn't change anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I've managed to resolve this problem, here is the solution:

### Usage

```
optionalAdress?.let {
    val mappedAdress = userDeliveryNetworkEntityMapper.mapToEntity(it).asHashMap(gson = gson)

    dbFunctions.getHttpsCallable("authOnCreate")
        .call(mappedAdress)
        .await()
}
```

### Converting Data Class

```
fun <T> T.asHashMap(gson: Gson): HashMap<String, Any> {
    return convert(gson)
}

private inline fun <I, reified O> I.convert(gson: Gson): O {
    val json = gson.toJson(this)
    return gson.fromJson(json, object : TypeToken<O>() {}.type)
}
```

### Cloud Function

```
export async function doOnAuthCreate(data: any) {
    functions.logger.info("AUTH ON CREATE - Creating new user");

    const company = data.company;
    functions.logger.info(`AUTH ON CREATE - Company is ${company}`)

    functions.logger.info("AUTH ON CREATE - Sucessfully created user");
}
```

### index.ts

```
export const authOnCreate = functions
    .region(region)
    .https
    .onCall(doOnAuthCreate);
```

IF one wants to use https functions in combination with the firebase functions emulator, you have to add the following to the app.onCreate() and inside the manifest:

### App

```
class App : Application() {
   override fun onCreate() {
     initOnTest()
   }
}

private fun initOnTest() {
    val fireStore = Firebase.firestore
    fireStore.useEmulator("10.0.2.2", 8080)

    val fireFunctions = Firebase.functions
    fireFunctions.useEmulator("10.0.2.2", 5001)

    val fireAuth = Firebase.auth
    fireAuth.useEmulator("10.0.2.2", 9099)

    val settings = FirebaseFirestoreSettings.Builder()
        .setPersistenceEnabled(false)
        .build()

    fireStore.firestoreSettings = settings
}
```

### Manifest (DONT USE IN PRODUCTION!!!!!)

```
<application
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```